# Shiny: dataTableProxy - function doesn't exist?

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I'm developing a Shiny application that provides interaction between a table with selection and a plot also with selection.   When the plot is clicked to select a point, I would like to cascade that selection to the table.  I've found this page (https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-proxy/) which describes exactly the process I'm trying to accomplish using dataTableProxy and selectRows functions.  But even their example code does not work on my machine.  I get an error saying "could not find function dataTableProxy"

I have version 0.1 of DT, shiny 0.12.2, shinydashboard 0.5.1, and R 3.1.2.  Even looking at the DT documentation I see no mention of a dataTableProxy function.

Comment: It's likely that it's in the dev version of `DT`. I also have version 0.1 and I don't have that function. There's been talks of version 0.2 coming out soon.

Comment: You can find the code [here](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/blob/master/R/shiny.R).

Comment: You need to use the development version of DT, download it  with `devtools::install_github('rstudio/DT')`

Comment: @brittenb - thanks for verification and the code link.  That works!

Comment: @daattali - excellent suggestion!

Comment: @DeanAttali: Can you add your comment as an answer?

Comment: I think it's irrelevant anymore because a new version was released on CRAN since then